# Paging does not work and maybe I found the cause

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, paging, facebook-fql

I am trying to implement the stream (news feed) paging function to my app, but it does not work as expected. I found many similar questions here but there are no solutions to solve this problem.

I tried both [Graph API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API) and [FQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Query_Language) and the behavior was similar. It succeeds to get the result one or two times but after that, it fails to get the result (gets the empty JSON array).

Finally, I found this problem depends on `access_token`. If I just change the source code to use Android SDK Stream Example App ID rather than my own App ID for authentication, it works perfectly.

So, I believe the Facebook server checks the App ID and returns some weird or restricted `access_token` to my app.

Are there any condition to get the valid `access_token`? I tried the exact same permissions with Android SDK Stream example app, but it could not solve the problem.

Will changing the App ID (to get the valid `access_token`) solve the case?

Comment: Can you provide some sample code that you're using at the minute? It's not really clear what you're doing.

Comment: What permissions does your app request?

Answer (score 1):

Verify your app has the `read_stream` permission. Without it you will not get any non-public objects.

There also seems to be some general LIMIT OFFSET issues with FQL and stream. See [Facebook FQL stream limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062085/facebook-fql-stream-limit) and http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/303076713093995.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Facebook SDK for Android. It can be found [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk). There are getter and setter methods to get and set the access token. The first time you do a [single sign-on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) (SSO), you must save the access token in SharedPreferences and there's no need to reauthenticate again and again.

Just set the access token from your preferences and make a call to the [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/). The *offline_access* permission is to be deprecated. The Facebook SDK for Android does the rest of the work. Just supply sufficient parameters through Bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the SDK on Facebook. Then get the access token.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The access token returned by Facebook server is valid only for a particular period of time. After which you need to refresh your access token, which is a tedious job.

So, in order to avoid this and maintain your token, you need to add the permission "offline_access" to your permission list. This is the approach used by almost Facebook-related apps.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things on Android:

- get right permissions "read_stream"
- Use the android SDK
- Check the sample that came w/ android. In the onCreate(), I authenticate Facebook object

  this.facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {....}
- Test using Facebook's Graph API Explorer.

If you paste in some code I can help you debug further.