# Facebook Open Graph API: weird behavior of parameter limit while getting a paginated user's news feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, pagination, limit, feed

I've written a little script in JAVA, that **tests the parameter `limit`** with four different values (10, 100, 1000 and 10000) when querying a **user's news feed of Facebook** using the **Open Graph API** and the [RestFB client](http://restfb.com/). As you'll see, it has a strange behavior...

**Scenario:**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // vars
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    FacebookClient client = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken);
    Connection<Post> home;
    List<Post> postList;
    Map<String, Post> postMap;
    int i;

    // limits to test
    String[] limits = {"10", "100", "1000", "10000"};
    for (String limit : limits) {

        // init list and map (looking for duplicate posts)
        postList = new LinkedList<Post>();
        postMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Post>();
        // get news feed
        home = client.fetchConnection(id + "/home", Post.class, Parameter.with("limit", limit));

        // going through pages
        i = 1;
        for (List<Post> page : home) {
            for (Post post : page) {
                // store into list
                postList.add(post);
                // store into map (unique post id)
                postMap.put(post.getId(), post);
            }
            i++;
        }

        // sort posts by created time
        Collections.sort(postList, new Comparator<Post>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Post post1, Post post2) {
                return post1.getCreatedTime().compareTo(post2.getCreatedTime());
            }
        });

        // log
        try {
            FileWriter out = new FileWriter("log/output.txt", true);
            out.write("LIMIT: " + limit + "\n");
            out.write("\tPAGES: " + (i - 1) + "\n");
            out.write("\tLIST SIZE: " + postList.size() + "\n");
            out.write("\tMAP SIZE: " + postMap.size() + "\n");
            out.write("\tOLDER POST: " + dateFormat.format(postList.get(0).getCreatedTime()) + "\n");
            out.write("\tYOUGNER POST: " + dateFormat.format(postList.get(postList.size() - 1).getCreatedTime()) + "\n");
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
LIMIT: 10
    PAGES: 7
    LIST SIZE: 56
    MAP SIZE: 56
    OLDER POST: 2009-03-22 14:58:03
    YOUGNER POST: 2012-05-11 15:48:49
LIMIT: 100
    PAGES: 3
    LIST SIZE: 174
    MAP SIZE: 172
    OLDER POST: 2012-01-12 23:01:34
    YOUGNER POST: 2012-05-11 15:48:49
LIMIT: 1000
    PAGES: 2
    LIST SIZE: 294
    MAP SIZE: 292
    OLDER POST: 2009-03-22 14:58:03
    YOUGNER POST: 2012-05-11 15:48:49
LIMIT: 10000
    PAGES: 2
    LIST SIZE: 294
    MAP SIZE: 292
    OLDER POST: 2009-03-22 14:58:03
    YOUGNER POST: 2012-05-11 15:48:49
```

**Interpretations and questions:**

1. Obviously, **you can't get all the posts** a user has had on his news feed since his account was created. Is limit limited?
2. With a `limit` of 100, 1000 and 10000, I must have had each time **two duplicated posts** within the whole returned news feed (174 - 172 = 194 - 192). Why? I never saw the same post twice on my personal news feed...
3. With (and only with) a `limit` of 100, the older post I get was created during the year 2012, meanwhile the other values of `limit` make the query retrieving a post that was created during the year 2009. I can understand that with an upper `limit` (1000 or 10000), the query retrieves older posts. But why does **a `limit` of 10 make the query retrieving an older post than a query limited by 100**?
4. Last but not least point: **I'm not getting the same number of posts**. Obviously, the more the `limit` is high, the more the number of retrieved posts is high. What I thought first, is that the only consequence of a smaller `limit` was an upper number of pages (which is the case though), but that the number of retrieved posts would not change. But it does. Why? That said, the number of posts seems to converge between a `limit` of 100 and 1000, because the number of posts is identical with a `limit` of 1000 and a `limit` of 10000.

PS: specifying a `since` and/or a `until` parameter to the query doesn't change anything.

Any answer/comment is welcome `:)`

Cheers.

**Edit:**

This is **my best [recall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall#Recall)**:

```
LIMIT: 200
    PAGES: 3
    LIST SIZE: 391
    MAP SIZE: 389
    OLDER POST: 2012-01-27 14:17:16
    YOUGNER POST: 2012-05-11 16:52:38
```

Why 200? Is it specified anywhere in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Its not in documentation but personally I have tested following for my project.

Facebook `limit` is limited to 500 posts. No matter you put a limit higher than 500 it will fetch only 500 results max. Try with 500 (or more), you will get maximum posts.

You wont get 500 posts every time but will get above 490 posts in general.
Some posts get filtered by various reasons (like privacy, blocked user, not suitable for specific region and other things)

This answers your 1st and 4th quetion.

For question no. 2 , I do not work in java, so I cant say if there's a prob in your code/logic or what your code is doing.

For question no. 3 , God help facebook !

**Edit**

For 4th problem, you may be hitting the queries/hour limit of graph api (facebook uses it to prevent spamming, you cant query apis frequently in quick succession)

Also,

[image: Facebook filter]

this is why, you do not get all results returned by facebook.

> (if you specified a limit of “5” but the five posts returned are not
>   visible to the viewer, you will get an empty result set.)
>
> In addition to the limits mentioned in the documentation for each of
>   the tables and connections listed above, it is helpful to know that
>   the maximum number of results we will fetch before running the
>   visibility checks is 5,000.

Reference: [Paging with graph api and fql](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/)

Also, there is a limit on no of results for a particular table. You can get a detail about them on respective fql tables.

For stream table (the one for posts/feed),

> Each query of the stream table is limited to the previous 30 days or
>   50 posts, whichever is greater, however you can use time-specific
>   fields such as created_time along with FQL operators (such as < or >)
>   to retrieve a much greater range of posts.

Reference: [Fql stream table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/)

**Look here too:**
[Facebook FQL stream limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062085/facebook-fql-stream-limit#answer-4102670)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already saw [the question you asked](http://goo.gl/P9kpP). Obviously, limit is limited, but that's weird we can't find any detail in the [doc](http://bit.ly/f5O0Oz). I personally can't get more than 389 posts, and that with a limit of 200 (see edit). So, I would have say that you can't get more than 400 posts, not 500. The 4 is more about the pagination: why does a limit of 10 make the query retrieving less posts than a limit of 100? That should only impact the number of pages of the pagination, not the number of posts.

Comment: Thanks, (even if I haven't answered all your questions, you gave me the prize). This is my first bounty, I am feeling happy ;)

Comment: Is there any paid api to get more than 1000/5000 comments

Comment: Contact facebook. They support giving informations by paying them.

Answer (score 3):

There is an ongoing bug in Facebook open graph API paging having to do with the limit parameter. The higher the limit, the more pages of posts --- as if a lower limit also culls a sampling of posts. The problem has surfaced and retreated ever since the post search function was down for a month in September.

A new bug has surfaced: at present a post search without an access_token and a small limit (like 12) will return few and sparsely populated results pages. The same search made with the access_token given in the API documentation example will give full pages of 12 results +/- and no skipping. I have no idea what kind of access_token they use, but no attempts on my part have duplicated their results. The post search without access token is more or less non-functional (again)!

Answer (score 0):

There could be some logic on facebook side to prevent data mining. Try add some delay while going through pages and see if better.