# I can't fetch more than 1000 replies from the Comments plugin

Tags: facebook

what I want to do is to get all of replies from here :

https://graph.facebook.com/293474140751567/comments

It doesn't matter if I get'em all at once (I know this isn't possible)

or get it separately by certain amount (I tried 500 at each using limit&offset params);

The problem is that I only can get max 1000 replies. (there are more than 2500 replies) 
If I set offset param to 1000, than I get no result at all.

Does anyone have an idea how to get all of the replies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to do with visibility. You're accessing comments which are available to everyone. Some users change their security / privacy settings, which prevents you from seeing them. It just happens to be that there are about 990 visible (public) comments on that post.

There's [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553510/facebook-open-graph-api-weird-behavior-of-parameter-limit-while-getting-a-pagin) on here which explains it much better than I can.

Comment: I want more than 1000-10000 comments to download from facebook.Is there any paid api present ?