# Facebook time based pagination gives wrong results

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.4

I've looked through Facebook Graph API [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api) and a few related topics such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356891/facebook-graph-api-pagination-is-not-giving-the-exact-result), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023757/how-does-paging-in-facebook-javascript-api-works) and even [this](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/). However I haven't found any solution.

I'm trying to analyse comments from [this](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=10151775534413086) post. As you can see there are dozens of comments under that post. What I want to achieve is that I want to be able to retrieve some number of comments by giving **start/end** dates to request. For instance, by giving an HTTP request with parameter **since=1375315200** (unix time) I expect to get all comments staring from **2013-08-01** (which is 1375315200 in unix time). However the following HTTP request:

```
curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/10151775534413086/comments?fields=created_time&offset=0&since=1375315200&limit=5&access_token={MY_TOKEN_HERE}"
```

Gives me the wrong result:

```
 {
  "data": [
    {
      "created_time": "2013-07-09T14:17:20+0000",
      "id": SOME_ID_HERE
    },
    {
      "created_time": "2013-07-09T18:03:17+0000",
      "id": SOME_ID_HERE
    },
    {
      "created_time": "2013-07-09T14:13:52+0000",
      "id": SOME_ID_HERE
    },
    {
      "created_time": "2013-07-09T14:22:16+0000",
      "id": SOME_ID_HERE
    },
    {
      "created_time": "2013-07-09T14:13:26+0000",
      "id": SOME_ID_HERE
    }
  ],
  "paging": { CURSORS DATA HERE }
}
```

Why does this result contain entries **before** **2013-08-01** (timestamps are less than **1375315200**)? Shouldn't that timestamps be **later** than **2013-08-01** (timestamps are greater than **1375315200**)? Is there any ideas/solutions how to do about this issue?

Comment: How do you know since is created_time? In your result it doesn't look sorted by created_time