# Using Graph API, why does changing limit change the total result set?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I try to get all likes for a post on Facebook, using the Graph API. I used the two following URLs (access token hidden):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/29576928167_10151158219658168/likes?since=1&limit=25&access_token=AAA...

https://graph.facebook.com/29576928167_10151158219658168/likes?since=1&limit=750&access_token=AAA...
```

Notice the only change is the `limit` parameter. When I use a limit of 25, I receive 42 pages of 25 likes each, and a final page of 7 likes, for a total number of 1057 likes. Using a limit of 750, I get a page of 99 likes, then a page with 307 results, then a page with 0 likes. My system stops when it encounters a page of 0 results. Total results, 406. In both cases, I follow the URLs as returned by Facebook, namely `paging.next`.

Does anybody know why changing the limit changes the **total** number of results?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062085/facebook-fql-stream-limit